# Is this the most efficient way of skipping random changesets when getting latest from TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

Is this the most efficient way of skipping random changesets when getting latest from TFS?

I have done a LOT of research into this subject and have yet to run across a solution. All comments / suggestions are welcome. Even if that suggestion is to use a completely different solution (that works).

My first attempt I filtered the changesets and then looped through them issuing a workspace.get(). This was incredibly slow, and did not get the right results. It ended up taking over 45 minutes for one folder where my final solution ended up taking 3:30 minutes for the same folder. Whereas a normal get process on the same folder took around 50 seconds each time.

This code is test code right now and is only intended to get this working and as such is missing basic things like exception handling and other best practices. It has passed all the tests I have thrown at it so far, but it is a bit slower than the normal get however I do not see a way to make it faster.

Here is what I ended up with:

**You will need references to**:

assemblyref://Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client&
assemblyref://Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common&
assemblyref://Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client&
assemblyref://Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common&
assemblyref://Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common

**The code**:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //these would be the changesets to ignore
        var ignoreChangeSets = new List<int>()
        {
            1,10,50,900 // change these to ids you want to ignore. These are just random example numbers
        };


        // Replace with your setup
        var tfsServer = @"http://server_name:8080/TFS/";
        var serverPath = @"$/TFS_PATH_TO_FOLDER/";

        // Connect to server
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServer));
        tfs.Connect(ConnectOptions.None);
        var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        //get both sets so we can do a comparison of the final changes
        var folderName = "Foo";
        var sourceDir = $@"{Path.GetTempPath()}\{folderName}\";
        var targetDir = $@"{Path.GetTempPath()}\{folderName}-ChangeSets\";

        //download the entire source
        DownloadSource(vcs, serverPath, sourceDir);



        var changeSets = GetChangeSets(vcs, serverPath);
        //technically this query could be anything. As long as it filters the changesets out.....
        //you could filter by user, date, info in the changesets, anything really. up to you.
        var filteredChangeSets = from cs in changeSets
                                 where !ignoreChangeSets.Contains(cs.ChangesetId)
                                 select cs;

        if (changeSets.Count() == filteredChangeSets.Count())
        {
            // we did not filter anything so do a normal pull as it is faster
            //download the entire source
            DownloadSource(vcs, serverPath, targetDir); 
        }
        else
        {
            GetChangeSetsLatest(vcs, serverPath, filteredChangeSets, targetDir);
        }

    }
    private static void RecreateDir(string dir)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.Delete(dir, true);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
    }

    private static GetStatus DownloadSource(VersionControlServer vcs, string serverPath, string dir)
    {
        string wsName = "TempWorkSpace";
        Workspace ws = null;
        try
        {
            ws = vcs.GetWorkspace(wsName, Environment.UserName);
        }
        catch (WorkspaceNotFoundException)
        {
            ws = vcs.CreateWorkspace(wsName, Environment.UserName);
        }

        RecreateDir(dir);
        ws.Map(serverPath, dir);

        var getResponse = ws.Get(VersionSpec.Latest, GetOptions.GetAll | GetOptions.Overwrite);

        vcs.DeleteWorkspace(wsName, Environment.UserName);
        return getResponse;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Changeset> GetChangeSets(VersionControlServer vcs, string serverPath)
    {
        VersionSpec versionFrom = null; // VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("C529", null);
        VersionSpec versionTo = VersionSpec.Latest;

        // Get Changesets
        var changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(
            serverPath,
            VersionSpec.Latest,
            0,
            RecursionType.Full,
            null,
            versionFrom,
            versionTo,
            Int32.MaxValue,
            true,
            false
            ).Cast<Changeset>();

        return changesets;
    }

    private static void GetChangeSetsLatest(VersionControlServer vcs, string serverPath, IEnumerable<Changeset> changesets, string dir)
    {
        //we are going to hold the latest item (file) in this dictionary, so we can do all our downloads at the end. The key will be the TFS server file path
        var items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
        RecreateDir(dir);

        //we need the changesets ordered by changesetid. 
        var changesetsOrdered = changesets.OrderBy(c => c.ChangesetId);

        //DO NOT PARALLEL HERE. We need these changesets in EXACT order
        foreach (var changeset in changesetsOrdered)
        {
            foreach (var change in changeset?.Changes.Where(i => i.Item.ItemType == ItemType.File))
            {
                var itemPath = change.Item.ServerItem.Replace(serverPath, dir).Replace("/", "\\");
                if (change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Edit) && change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.SourceRename))
                {
                    if (change.Item.DeletionId == 0)
                    { items.AddOrUpdate(change.Item.ServerItem, change.Item); }
                    else
                    { items.TryRemove(change.Item.ServerItem); }
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Delete) && change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.SourceRename))
                {
                    var previousChange = GetPreviousServerChange(vcs, change.Item);
                    if (previousChange != null) { items.TryRemove(previousChange?.Item.ServerItem); }

                    if (change.Item.DeletionId == 0)
                    { items.AddOrUpdate(change.Item.ServerItem, change.Item); }
                    else
                    { items.TryRemove(change.Item.ServerItem); }
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Rollback) && change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Delete))
                {
                    items.TryRemove(change.Item.ServerItem);
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Rollback))
                {
                    var item = GetPreviousServerChange(vcs, change.Item)?.Item;
                    if (item != null) { items.AddOrUpdate(item.ServerItem, item); }
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Add) || change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Edit) || change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Rename))
                {
                    if (change.Item.DeletionId == 0) { items.AddOrUpdate(change.Item.ServerItem, change.Item); }
                }
                else if (change.ChangeType.HasFlag(ChangeType.Delete))
                {
                    items.TryRemove(change.Item.ServerItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Unknown change types: {change.ChangeType.ToString()}");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
            }
        }

        //HUGE penalty for switching to parallel, stick to single file at a time, one test went from 3:30 to 11:05. File system does not appreciate threading. :|
        //Parallel.ForEach(items, (i) =>
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemPath = item.Key.Replace(serverPath, dir).Replace("/", "\\");
            item.Value.DownloadFile(itemPath);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value.ChangesetId + " - " + itemPath);
        };
    }

    //really not sure this is the right way to do this. works quite well, but it begs the question that surely there must be an easier way?
    private static Change GetPreviousServerChange(VersionControlServer vcs, Item item)
    {
        //get the changesets and reverse their order, so we can take the next one after it
        var changesets = GetChangeSets(vcs, item.ServerItem).OrderByDescending(cs => cs.ChangesetId);

        //skip until we find our changeset, then take the following changeset
        var previousChangeSet = changesets.SkipWhile(c => c.ChangesetId != item.ChangesetId).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

        //return the Change that matches the itemid (file id)
        return previousChangeSet?.Changes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Item.ItemId == item.ItemId);
    }

}

static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
    public static void TryRemove<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I am being forced into this because of existing business procedures. Multiple teams or devs can work on the same database at the same time. The changes per team or dev are cataloged under an RFC #. Each RFC # can have its own release schedule and release at any various point in time. I will use Red Gate SQL Compare to compare the folder with everything (as the source) to the folder minus the RFC change-sets (as the target) to generate a change script for that RFC.

Then there are these rules:

- An RFC can get parked for an indeterminate period of time. For example I have seen RFC's parked in Staging for over a year. Other RFC's will pass by this RFC on their way to production.
- Individual RFC's can be withdrawn from a production push at the last minute.

The chance of me changing these existing procedures is nil. So I had to figure out a way to work around them. This was that way. I would prefer to follow a normal release schedule of pushing all changes out every release that then flow all the way to production. Unfortunately that is not the case here.

Comment: I smell an X-Y problem... what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Essentially I want to compare a db project versus the same db project minus some changesets. We mark our change sets with a RFC number when performing database checkins and often there are multiple people working on the same database in different RFC's. Not all RFC's release at the same pace or schedule. So I need to build a change script with just a particular RFC's changes. Not an x-y problem at all. Unless the business process change I have to continue do it this way. NOTE: We are switching to using db projects which is he causality of this need.

Comment: What you're trying to do is going to cause you endless headaches, bugs and failed deployments. The correct solution is to properly isolate work in progress so only completed features are merged into a stable mainline for release, then applying schema changes as part of your deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to have a Release branch and a Dev branch. Every check-in is then done in the Dev branch when the work is done. Whenever an RFC is approved for release you do a merge of that particular changeset from Dev to Release followed by whatever steps you need for your release.

Depending on the complexity of your development and releases you might need more branches of each, but I would suggest to aim for as few branches as possible, because it tends to get complicated very fast.

Comment: Tore, and @danielmann Neither route is possible because of existing business procedures that are not going to change. I understand normal release procedures but rules here do not allow normal. The two main rules that block this: 1) An RFC can be "parked" into an environment and left there for a long time. I've seen a year and half so far parked in Stage. 2) An RFC can be withdrawn from a release push at the last minute.  
I do not go down this path without good reasons and without having thought it out very thoroughly. Using a dacpac compare or single release script will not work.